# Get Ioc binded object at Adonis v5

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I use `ioc.bind` and `ioc.use` at adonis v4, and now at adonis v5, how do I use `ioc.use`?
[image]

I want to reuse the instance `Container/MerchantService` and get the base url or call the function inside `Container/MerchantService`

I try to find it in adonis documentation and got nothing.